# Get also elements that don't match fnmatch

Tags: python, glob, recursive-datastructures, fnmatch

I'm using a recursive glob to find and copy files from a drive to another

```py
def recursive_glob(treeroot, pattern):
   results = []
   for base, dirs, files in os.walk(treeroot):

      goodfiles = fnmatch.filter(files, pattern)
      results.extend(os.path.join(base, f) for f in goodfiles)

return results
```

Works fine. But I also want to have access to the elements that don't match the filter.

Can someone offer some help? I could build a regex within the loop, but there must be a simpler solution, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, use a set:

```
goodfiles = fnmatch.filter(files, pattern)
badfiles = set(files).difference(goodfiles)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another loop inside the `os.walk` loop can also be used:

```
goodfiles = []
badfiles = []
for f in files:
  if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, pattern):
    goodfiles.append(f)
  else:
    badfiles.append(f)
```

Note: With this solution you have to iterate through the list of files just once. In fact, the `os.path.join` part can be moved to the loop above.