# Negating a fnmatch pattern

Tags: python, glob, fnmatch

Consider this pattern: `*.py`. It matches all the paths ending with the `py` extension. Now, is it possible to find a pattern which matches **everything else**?

I thought this would do it: `*[!.][!p][!y]`, but apparently [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/fnmatch.html) always returns `False` with this.

I'd like to avoid regexes. I know I could use them, but in this case it isn't possible.

Comment: FYI, `fnmatch` does **not** always return `False` for your proposed pattern: `fnmatch.fnmatch("blah","*[!.][!p][!y]")` returns `True`. The behavior you're probably observing is that `*[!.][!p][!y]` must necessarily return `False` whenever the third-from-last character is `.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally prefer regex, but if you'd prefer fnmatch, you could do:

```
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*[!p][!y]'):
        print(file)
```

Comment: Yes, I know I could do something like this. But I was actually looking for a *pattern* because I have to use it in a `--exclude` option of a program that uses fnmatch.

Comment: @rubik I don't get what the difficulty is in using this approach? Could you possibly explain a bit further?

Comment: @JonClements: This approach is not difficult *per se*, it just doesn't fit my use-case. I'm using a program that analyzes some files. I can exclude the files with an `--exclude` option that takes fnmatch patterns. There is no `--include` option.  Since I want to exclude everything that isn't a Python file, I was curious if there was such a pattern.

Comment: @JonClements: It is not. By pattern I mean the second argument to `fnmatch.fnmatch`. The pattern I'm looking for doesn't match Python files but matches everything else. Think of this situation as if I could only change the second argument of `fnmatch` but I couldn't touch anything else.

Comment: I've updated the pattern -- but I recommend you consider rethinking your pattern.  A quick scan of fnmatch and glob's source shows they each are using regex under the hood.

Comment: I see, but if I try it I always get `False`. I'm beginning to think that what I want to achieve is not possible with `fnmatch`.

Comment: Works for me... `[f for f in os.listdir('.') if fnmatch.fnmatch(f, '*[!py]')] == ['admin.pyc', 'ajax.pyc', ...]`

Comment: I tested it before posting -- are you sure you are getting false? Can you post a bit more your question about how your using the code?

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong in the terminal. Trying it on real paths showed that it works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. FYI -- if you want to consider regex on another project, you can read this excellant article (which posts a specific example of how to match negated file extensions) -- https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions

Comment: Thanks for the resource! Also, I discovered that your pattern fails to match `filename.yp`. I discovered that instead `*[!p][!y]` does its job. If you want to add this to your answer to make it more complete it would be great.

Comment: `*[!p][!y]` matches anything that does **not** have `p` as its second-from-last character **and** does not have `y` as its last character. For instance, Perl scripts with the `.pl` extension will be excluded.

Comment: @KyleStrand so the accepted answer regex '*[!p][!y]' is wrong, because it also exclude sth like: `.pl`, `hy`. Is there a way to exclude whole sentence instead of singular characters?

Comment: @murt As far as I know, not with `fnmatch`, because `fnmatch` is based on Unix filename globs, which are much less powerful than true regex. In true regex, this is trivial: `(\.py)!` excludes anything with the characters `.py`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the only absolutely correct answer is to generate the list of *unwanted* files, then find the *difference* between this list and the complete (unfiltered) file list. (This technique can be seen here, using `set`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8645326/1858225)

There does not appear to be any built-in option for negating the search pattern in the `fnmatch` module.

For an example of why character-wise negation won't work, see my comment on user590028's answer.

Comment: Interesting approach, which also seems to be the most correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If files is a list of files, then this code will exclude all files matching *.py pattern using fnmatch.filter.  This should be the correct answer.

```
exclude = '*.py'
for f in fnmatch.filter(files, exclude):
    files.remove(f)
```